# Want one value per id from multiple value per id

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, groupwise-maximum

I have a dataframe in which one ID has multiple value assign. But I want one ID and one value which is highest

Given dataset
Id.                       Class
111.                  Metro
111.                   Urban
111.                 Rural
222.                 Rural
333.                Urban
333.                  Metro

Here Metro> Urban> Rural
So I want

Id.   Class
111.    Metro
222.    Rural
333.    Metro.  By removing duplicates in ids

Comment: This would benefit from providing the exact structure of your dataframe as a code-chunk.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas DataFrames has a built in function that removes duplicates:

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

Which, in turn, has an attribute `subset` in which the column of interest can be targeted.

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[“column_name”])
```

Comment: Yes, but I want one value per id. Here, for id 111 i have 3 values. But I want the highest one